# How to convert a ndarray into a EagerTensor due to differing dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am following the notebook on TF-Hub: Fast Style Transfer for Arbitrary Style and am having difficulties importing my own images. Some background, this notebook basically does image augmentation using 2 input images.

Here is the code: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization.ipynb

I am importing images through:

```
img = cv.imread('path_to_directory')
img = np.float32(img)
```

which gives me **ndarray with shape (256, 256, 3)**.

However, the images being used in the original notebook are of **EagerTensor with shape (1, 256, 256, 3)**.

When I run the image generator:

```
outputs = hub_module(tf.constant(content_image), tf.constant(style_image))
stylized_image = outputs[0]
```

> InvalidArgumentError:  The first dimension of paddings must be the rank of inputs[4,2], [256,256,3]
> [[node transformer/contract/MirrorPad (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/module_v2.py:106) ]] [Op:__inference_pruned_12110]

and if I understood correctly, it is expecting a 4 dimensional image which mine is only of 3 dimensions. I am not sure what the 2 means. As such, I believe it is due to the differing input shapes.

Could someone explain what exactly is the difference between the 2 images and how exactly do I convert the first to the second format? If I have misunderstood the error and the problem was not because of the image dimensions, please correct me. Thank you.

Edit:
After running the code:

```
tf.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL2d7.png)

The image appears to become discoloured as shown in the link.

Comment: does `img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)` solve the issue?

Comment: It means you need to add batch dimension, expand dims will simply solve the issue.

Comment: When I add the batch dimensions, the image appears to be distorted with the error: WARNING:matplotlib.image:Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).